# I turned my PC off during reinstallation

Tags: upgrade

I wanted to upgrade my Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.10 (I think, not sure now). I clicked the "upgrade button" and wrote the password as usual. For few moments I saw that the computed was doing something, but then suddenly the screen went black, only the Caps Lock light was flashing.

I left the computer for few hours (at least 5 or 6), but when I got back, it was still the same way. I was worried, so I turn the PC off and turned it on again. It kinda worked, but the only think that actually started, was something that looked like and worked as commander.

I want to finish the upgrade or at least return to the previous version, but I don't know how... Do I have to reinstall it all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you will have to reinstall.  Choose the "something else" option, and configure your existing root ( / ) and swap partitions, and do NOT check the format box on the root partition, and all of your personal files will remain intact.

Comment: I think you need to make the same username and password too in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Step 1: Boot into Ubuntu Live-Usb

Step 2: Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Step 3: Login as user with administrator permissions.

```
sudo -i
```

Step 4: Find out how your partition / is called with fdisk.

```
fdisk -l
```

Step 5: Suppose it is /dev/sda1, mount the partition in /mnt, previous fsck

```
umount /dev/sda1
fsck -a /dev/sda1
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Step 6: Mount the following paths in the respective locations in the /mnt 
namely – /dev, /sys, /proc, and /dev/pts.

```
mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
```

Step 7: chroot into the Ubuntu partition

```
chroot /mnt
```

Step 8: Try repairing the installed system. Execute these commands:

```
dpkg-reconfigure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install 
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Step 9: Un-mount the previously mounted directories and reboot.

```
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/dev/pts
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt
reboot
```